# Form submit callback returning multiple times? And how to create a function for a null value in another function?

Tags: jquery, forms, variables, submit

Sorry for the double question, I'm encountering a few issues as I try to crack this password change form. This is a follow on from my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16602448/with-multiple-if-else-statements-how-do-you-submit-a-form-only-if-they-all-re) about submitting a form only if the 'if' statements return true.

I have a **keyup** function that runs through if/else statements to check that a password conforms to a number of requirements.  For example, if it is longer than 7 characters, if it contains a capital letter, if it contains 2 numbers etc.
I have created a global variable 'rtnTrue = 1' that I set as 0 on the else statements inside the keyup function (if they fail one of the requirements then rtnTrue = 0).  So the theory is that if rtnTrue = 1, then the form can be submitted, otherwise it can't.

I have 2 problems:

1. Even with the variable global, I still need to set another rule
   on the submit action because the rtnTrue will only happen when the
   user types something in the password input box.  E.g. if they just
   press submit without typing anything, then rtnTrue = 1 anyway so
   it'll submit.  I need something along the lines of pwd.length == 0
   but I'm not too sure how to do that because of this variable being
   inside the keyup function?
2. If I type something incorrect in the box and click submit, my callback alert is showing up 3 times and I don't know why!

Here's my JS code and I've created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ZncQx/) because it's quite long!

```
var rtnTrue = 1;

$('#password-info').hide();

$('#form-password-change #input-password').keyup(function() {

    // keyup code here
    // set password variable
    var pwd = $(this).val();

    // validate the length
    if (pwd.length > 7) {
        $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        rtnTrue = 0;
    }

    // RegExp
    // validate letter
    if ( /([^a-z]*[a-z]){3,}/i.test(pwd) ) {
        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        rtnTrue = 0;
    }

    // validate repeated letters (none repeated more than twice)
    if ( /([A-Za-z])(.*?\1){2}/.test(pwd) ) {
        $('#letter .repeated').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        $('#letter').addClass('invalid-repeated');
    } else {
        $('#letter .repeated').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        $('#letter').removeClass('invalid-repeated');
        rtnTrue = 0;
    }

    // validate capital letter
    if (pwd.match(/[A-Z]/)) {
        $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        rtnTrue = 0;
    }

    // validate number
    if ( /([^\d]*[\d]){2,}/.test(pwd) ) {
        $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
    } else {
        $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        rtnTrue = 0;
    }

    // validate repeated numbers (none repeated more than twice)
    if ( /([\d])(.*?\1){2}/.test(pwd) ) {
        $('#number .repeated').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
        $('#number').addClass('invalid-repeated');
    } else {
        $('#number .repeated').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
        $('#number').removeClass('invalid-repeated');
        rtnTrue = 0;
    }

    passwordFormSubmit(); // New Function

}).focus(function() {
    // focus code here
    $('#password-info').slideDown('fast');

}).blur(function() {
    // blur code here
    $('#password-info').show();
});

function passwordFormSubmit() { 

    var local = rtnTrue;

    if (rtnTrue==1) {
        $('#form-password-change').submit(function(){
            return true;
        });
    }else {
        $('#form-password-change').submit(function(){
            alert(rtnTrue);
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like several coding issues, and I would suggest a few changes.. never.. NEVER declare a variable as global. 

[Create a container object.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5823802/programming-oop-in-javascript-properly/13074212#13074212) 
and control you functionality from there. Also, setting your variable as true initially does not make sense because only upon valid entry should you allow a form to be submitted.. I would personally set up a set of false member variables that are set to true when each required action occurs. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Brett Weber.  I had a look through your link and was immediately bamboozled because I think it's beyond my knowledge, so all looks a bit confusing.  I've changed the variable to false as per your recommendation, but think I need to look into the basics of JS objects.

Comment: Once you start digging, the organization and ability to modulize functionality is fascinating, not to mention much safer! I would highly recommend looking into closures and (though often looked over) the syntax of C# classes to get some inspiration on building and breaking your functionality into functional modules, and please note if you would like further assistance in your process of understanding, I'm happy to help as I was and am helped.

Comment: @Brett Weber do you have time to update my fiddle ([this one has global variable moved](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ZncQx/23/)) to get started on creating my the object.  I don't want you to write all the code, that's not the point of learning, but a starting point could really help me.

Comment: Let me know if the answer I posted is the kind of help you were needing, if not I may be able to set something up with a bit more details. The route I posted is the route i would personally take, but using the data method of jquery is just preference, creating a variable works just as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZncQx/33/

Answer (score 0):

If you do want some quick ways to achieve your goal, I modified your JSFiddle.
Try using true / false instead of 0 or 1.
And you are currently trying to submit the form every time the user types. You will see what I did in JSFiddle.

And try setting the first variable to false, so that if the user click submit button with no input, it will not submit.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZncQx/22/

```
var passwordFine = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by modulizing your code and defining your vars and expanding your process bit:

```
(function()
{
   var bPasswordValid = false;
   var txtInput       = $('selector');
   var btnSubmit      = $('selector');

   txtInput.data("IsValid", false);

   txtInput.on("change", Validate); // Setting to change instead of keyup should optimize your code unless you are stripping values if they are not valid
   btnSubmit.on("click", ValidateAll); // Setting to click could be replaced by someForm.on("submit", ValidateAll) if enter key is not caught by click handler

   var Validate = function(oEvent) 
   {
      // Check if the input is valid
      var sVal = $(this).val();

      if (sVal /* passes validation */ )
         txtInput.data("IsValid", true);
   } 

   var ValidateAll = function(oEvent)
   {
      if ( txtInput.data("IsValid") )
         return;
      else 
      {
         // Do some validation msg stuff
         return false; // prevent form from being submitted
      }
   }
}())
```

This should give you a good push in the right direction, and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZncQx/33/) a fiddle to see a mostly working module

Comment: That's great, thanks!  I've tried this, but can't get it to work.  I've been through the code and tried to work out what exactly is going on, and I think I get it.  I decided to remove the .data and try with variables (mainly because I wanted to prove that I understood, but partly because you declared the variable at the top and I wondered if that was a start of doing it that way).  I've [tried to validate just the length on my new JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/ZncQx/26/), but it's not working!  Not getting any errors from Inspector, and can't work out what's wrong.

Comment: Well, I'll have to take a look after work today, but I'll check in to see what is going on, But I can't promise anything more taht javascript and jquery because I do not know much in the context you are working. :) I'm glad to lead you in the right direction, though!